# Spring Jackson - bidirectional relationship - expand references in JSON

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

I have two classes, owner and bicycle. Owner references a list of bicycles. Bicycle references an owner.

When querying, I would like for the json returned to expand the references down one level. So each bicycle record would expand the owner ref. And each owner record would expand each bicycle ref. Of course I want to avoid infinte recursion!

So this is what I want.

> ~$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -k -w "\n"
>   https://mint191:8453/api/v1/bicycles [    {       "id": 1,        "model":
>   "civic",      "owner": {          "id": 1,            "userName": "user1"         }   },  {
>         "id": 2,        "model": "montpellier",         "owner": {          "id": 2,
>             "userName": "user2"         }   },  {       "id": 3,        "model": "cambridge",
>         "owner": {          "id": 3,            "userName": "user3",        }   },  {       "id": 4,
>         "model": "tern A7",         "owner": {          "id": 2,            "userName": "user2"
>         }   } ]
>
> ~$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -k -w "\n"
>   https://mint191:8453/api/v1/owners [  {       "id": 1,        "userName":
>   "user1",      "bicycles": [           {
>                 "id": 1,
>                 "model": "civic",           }       ]   },  {       "id": 2,        "userName": "user2",        "bicycles": [           {
>                 "id": 2,
>                 "model": "montpellier"          },          {
>                 "id": 4,
>                 "model": "tern A7"          }       ]   },  {       "id": 3,        "userName": "user3",        "bicycles": [           {
>                 "id": 3,
>                 "model": "cambridge",           }       ]   } ]

And here are the classes. As the code is, the two rest api calls above would cause infinite recursion.

```
public class Owner {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "owner_gen")
   private long id;
   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 4, max = 10)
   private String userName;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "owner")
   private List<Bicycle> bicycles; 
}


public class Bicycle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "bike_gen")
    private long id;
    private String model;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
    private Owner owner;
}
```

So far I have tried @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference. The class using @JsonBackReference is not expanded, the class using @JsonManagedReference is expanded. And no inifite recursion. So nearly there.

I have also tried @JsonIdentityInfo. Here the problem is that any record is only fully listed once. Once listed, any further refs to that record are simply the id. So if an owner has multiple bicycles, listing the bicycles will show the expanded owner for bike A but just an owner id for bike B because that owner has already been included in the response.

I don't think I am asking for something particularly unusual (?) and looking at various pages always use very simple data or only approach the data from one direction. I realise it is more data but it does make any programming much easier.

Do I need a custom serializer?

Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: Please do not describe code and structeres, show them. Try for a [mre].

Comment: Updated yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

This what I did.

I removed all jackson annotations from the models

In the service layer, for getbicycle? (singular, plural) and getowner?(plural/singular) I added code eg getBicycles()

```
public Collection<Bicycle> getBicycles() {
    Collection<Bicycle>bicycles = new ArrayList<>();  
    bicycleRepo.findAll().forEach(bicycles::add);  
    for (Bicycle b: bicycles) {
        b.getOwner().setBicycles(null);
    }
    return bicycles;  
}
```

and getOwners()

```
public Collection<Owner> getOwners() {
    Collection<Owner>owners = new ArrayList<>();  
    ownerRepo.findAll().forEach(owners::add);  

    for  (Owner o : owners) {
        for (Bicycle b : o.getBicycles()) {
            b.setOwner(null);
        } 
    }
    return owners;  
}
```

The result is not perfect - there is a null printed in the referenced object but it odes give me what I want.